# Specifying the relative dimension of views in a layout based on device screen width/height

Tags: android, layout

I am writing an android application that has 3 `views` one below the other.

Each view has to be of equal height, depending on the screen size.

Each view occupies the full width of the screen.

How do you specify in the `layout xml` that the view has to take up 1/3rd height of the device display height?

What would be the appropriate `layout` to use in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try **android:layout_weight="1"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<View  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#F00"
    />
<View  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#0F0"
    />
<View  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00F"
    />
```

Comment: How does this specify the height to be equally distributed?

Comment: From the android docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html  Look for the weight explanation under  the LinearLayout section.

Comment: Specifying android:layout_weight="1" for each child view will direct  layout to distribute height equally. Please refer to docs pointed by Scott.